# Reusable DropDownList Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and am looking for help with the following issue.

I have a DropDownList control in a view. The selected value will be stored in an integer field  of my model.

My preference is to not hard code the text and values in markup. In addition, I'd like to be able to use this same list of text and values in DropDownList controls in other views.

I'm not sure if I need to create a class that initializes these values somewhere, or perhaps I need an extension method. I could use some guidance on the best way to approach this.

Comment: would using a partial view fit your needs?

Comment: @chardymcdennis: I wouldn't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample:

```
var apps = _webAppRepo.GetAll();

IList<SelectListItem> appSelectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (var item in apps) {

    appSelectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem {
        Text = item.ApplicationName,
        Value = item.WebApplicationID.ToString()
    });
}

ViewBag.AppSelectListItems = appSelectListItems;
```

And this is how you use it on you view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => 
      model.WebApplicationID, 
      (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AppSelectListItems
)
```

If you would like to use it without a model, this is the way:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Foo", 
      (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AppSelectListItems
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of doing this, but you could do worse than storing these values in a view model, and rendering them on the page.  I'm just using a `Tuple` here as an example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    List<Tuple<int, string>> items_ = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        items_.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(1, "Item1"));
        items_.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(2, "Item2"));
        // etc
    }

    public List<Tuple<int, string>> Items { get { return items_; } }
}
```

Your controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }
}
```

Your view:

```
@model MyNameSpace.MyViewModel


<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect>
    @{foreach(Tuple<int, string> item in Model.Items){
        <option value="@item.Item1">@item.Item2</option>
    }}
</select>
```

Obviously, you can also make an extention method to create combo boxes in more interesting ways :)

Comment: Woww, you explored the America all over again. Why not use one of the built in Html Helpers?

Comment: @tugberk, the main purpose was to display storing items for a combo-box in a view model.

Comment: That is true as well and your approach is totally legitimate but still looks not right to me. MVC team has created a class just for that purpose: `SelectListItem`

Comment: @tugberk, well there you go.  All this time with MVC and I didn't know about that.  I admit that most of my HTML/CSS is designed and done by a non-programmer who doesn't know C#, so I generally use what he has done in my views and "plug-in" all the necessary bits/partials.

Answer (score 0):

You should populate your DropDownList from a database table, or from memory o reading from a xml file.

The you should be able to use the same data to populate any other ddl on your views.